# Wordpress meta_query of certain days after date stored in custom field

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I like to set meta_query for 10 days after date stored in custom field.

I set like this, but it does not work.

Meta key '2a' has value like '2022-02-15'.

```
<?php
$today = wp_date('Y-m-d');


$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
                      'relation' => 'AND',


array(
    'key'=> '2a',
    'value' => array( date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 day", strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID , '2a' ,true)))),  $today ),
    'compare' => '<=',
    'type' => 'DATE',
    ),

array(
    'key'=> '3a',
    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),


                                                                                             
));?>
```

Comment: So you're aiming to get posts between a given date (+10 days) and today? If you remove that portion of the meta query, are posts found? Of the posts that are returned, are there posts which would match the date query as well? Happy to help fix the issue but worth being sure you've ruled out simple problems first.

Comment: Yes.  It works without this portion.  I like  to query all articles that exceed over 10days of meta key '2a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing two values into the date portion of your query which suggests you need to compare between as opposed to `<=`.

I tend to find it's better to perform calculations first and then pass the result into the query. Merging it all together as in your example makes it much harder to follow.

While `strtotime()` will work, there are classes that make handling time easier and more readable.

Example:

```
// Keeping the code brief for the example but you'll probably want to do some checks here.
$twoADate = new DateTimeImmutable( get_post_meta( $post->ID , '2a' ,true ) );

$tenDaysLater = $twoADate->modify( '+10 days' )->format( 'Y-m-d' );
$today = wp_date( 'Y-m-d' );

$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'=> '2a',
            'value' => [$tenDaysLater, $today],
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE', 
        ],
        [
            'key' => '3a',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea.  I agree its easier to separate caculation.  I like to set condition like this.  If '$today' is more than '$tenDaysLater'.  I mean I like to query all articles which has meta value of '2a' before 2022-03-31.  It does not query when meta value is '2022-04-02' or something that is less 10days passed.  So, I changed 'BETWEEN' to '<', but it does not work yet.    It shows all article that '3a' is exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$today = wp_date('Y-m-d');
$TenDaysBefore = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-10 day", strtotime($today)));

'key'=> '2a',
'value' => $TenDaysBefore ,
'compare' => '<=',
'type' => 'DATE',
```

Works now